# trying to use the Class keyword and modules in es6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I found this code in a book:

```
class Animal(){
    constructor(){
        this.legs = 4;
        this.eyes = 2;
        this.say = "Huh?"
     }
     speak(){
         console.log(this.say)
     }
}
```

The above should be the right way to define a class but I can't use this in FF or chrome. I got `SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier`

Also I was playing around with modules. I put

`export let hello = "hello from the first module"` in a firstModule.js file

than I put

```
import {hello} from "firstModule"
console.log(hello)
```

in a main.js file

and i put `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>` in the index file and i got `SyntaxError: modules are not implemented yet`

I guess I'm having problems using es6 syntax that I thought I will be able to esspecially if use babeljs

I hope you could see in this babel "try it out" [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%09%20%09class%20Animal()%7B%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09constructor()%7B%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%09this.legs%20%3D%204%3B%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%09this.eyes%20%3D%202%3B%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%09this.say%20%3D%20%22Huh%3F%22%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%7D%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09speak()%7B%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%09console.log(this.say)%0A%09%20%09%20%09%09%7D%0A%09%20%09%20%09%7D) that I attempted to use the class statement but i got an error `Unexpected token (1:15)` .

How can use es6 stuff? I thought babel was supposed to translate es6 to es5. what am i doing wrong?

I also put `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` in the html file

Comment: Are you actually using babeljs to transpile ES6 code into ES5 code and you then run the ES5 code in the browser?  Or are you trying to run ES6 code directly in a browser?  You mention both - which are you trying to do?

Comment: Here’s [Mozilla’s progress on implementing `class` syntax](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=837314) and here’s [Chrome’s progress](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3330).

Comment: I was trying to use ES6 code and output it to the  browser. i was doing research on why it doesnt work and I heard that bablejs takes ES6 and translates it to Es5 code so I could use it in the browser for testing. OKM, below said that the difficulties I was having with the class part of my question was because I put parenthesis.  I got the  es5 code from the bable website. but if i remove the parenthesis  in my editor. It still doesn't work. so I guess I should copy and paste it.

Comment: What does "output it to the browser" mean? By the way, it's "Babel", as in the tower of Babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `class Animal` instead of `class Animal()`.
To use ES6 code in your browser before it supports what you are using, you need babel to transpile the code to ES5. For example, [in browser](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_in_browser)

```
<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
```

To play around with modules, you could try them with `babel-node`, or could pack js files using webpack and load the result in browser.

Comment: Im not sure what  transpile  means. but If I wanted to use es6 i could make the js file and npm install bablejs and put some code in cmd promp on windows and it would translate the js file to es5 and i would upload that to a server. If that's the case I guess the best route would be using some method on https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ .. what does "output to stdout." mean on that page ?  is `babel script.js` the cmd i give to translate the file. sory. Im a novice.

Comment: @user2537537 Yes, it is one of ways. By using `babel script.js > build/script.js`, you get browser-ready ES5 code in `build/script.js`. Normally, people would use some build systems such as `gulp` or `webpack` to help invoke babel and build packed JS which is more suitable for publish. See ways in https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/

Comment: stdout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29